# Putting a default value as a difference of two columns in Mysql while creating a table

Tags: mysql, generated-columns

Can we create a table in Mysql server with a column as the difference between two other columns. So when those two columns are populated the third column will be computed from them.

```
CREATE TABLE LOAD(
START_TIME DATETIME,
END_TIME DATETIME,
ELAPSED_TIME DATETIME AS START_TIME-END_TIME
)
```

Something like this

Comment: Be wary of storing easily derivable data

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 8 does indeed support [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html). So to have a generated column `elapsed_time` which has the seconds passed between a column `start_time` and `end_time`, you could use `timestampdiff()` like:

```
CREATE TABLE `load`
             (start_time datetime,
              end_time datetime,
              elapsed_time integer AS (timestampdiff(SECOND, start_time, end_time)));
```

(Note that `load` is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html#keywords-8-0-detailed-L) and therefore needs to be enclosed in backticks when used as an identifier.)
[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51af885aecbde55f6565bcae588326aa)

Comment: It is giving an error while creating the table.                    Incorrect syntax near keyword 'AS'